# Swift 4 Cannot convert value of type '[String : AnyObject]?' to expected argument type '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]?'

Tags: swift4, xcode9

I have just updated to Xcode 9 and converted my app from swift 3 to swift 4.
I have graphs which use strings to label the axes and other variables.
So I have a moneyAxisString = "Money".
Previously I was able to draw them using this code:

```
moneyAxisString.draw(in: CGRect(x: CGFloat(coordinateXOriginLT + axisLength/3), y: CGFloat(coordinateYOriginRT + axisLength + 5 * unitDim), width: CGFloat(300 * unitDim), height: CGFloat(100 * unitDim)), withAttributes: attributes as? [String : AnyObject])
```

Where attributes is a dictionary defined as follows

```
 attributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: fieldColor,
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: fieldFont!,
        NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: style

    ]
```

Now my app won't compile and I am getting the message:

Cannot convert value of type '[String : AnyObject]?' to expected argument type '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]?'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a type mismatch: `[String : AnyObject]` is clearly not `[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]`

<kbd>⌥-click</kbd> on `NSAttributedStringKey` to see the declaration.

---

The solution is to declare `attributes` as

```
var attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]()
```

to remove the down cast

```
 ..., withAttributes: attributes)
```

and to write simply

```
attributes = [.foregroundColor: fieldColor,
              .font: fieldFont!,
              .paragraphStyle: style]
```

Comment: When I remove the downcast I get: Cannot convert value of type 'NSDictionary' to expected argument type '[NSAttributedStringKey : Any]?' and it then says: Insert ' as! [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]' . Also, when I shorten the code for attributes it says "Expression resolves to an unused l-value" and "Expected expression" and "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'. Insert ";". Is it relevant that I initially defined attributes as: var attributes: NSDictionary = [:]

Comment: Declare `var attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]()` rather than `NSDictionary`, then you can even remove the annotation. Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift anyway.

Answer (score 3):

`NSAttributedStringKey` was changed to a struct in Swift 4. However, other objects that *use* `NSAttributedStringKey` apparently didn't get updated at the same time.

The easiest fix, *without having to change any of your other code*, is to **append** `.rawValue` to *all* your occurrences of `NSAttributedStringKey` setters - turning the key names into `String`s:

```
let attributes = [
    NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue:  UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 15.0)!,
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.white
] as [String : Any]
```

Note that you won't need the `!` at the `as` now, either.

Alternatively, you can skip the `as` cast at the end by declaring the array to be `[String : Any]` upfront:

```
let attributes: [String : Any] = [
    NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue:  UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 15.0)!,
    NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.white
]
```

Of course, you still need to append the `.rawValue` for each `NSAttributedStringKey` item you set.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class func getCustomStringStyle() -> [NSAttributedStringKey: Any]
    {
        return [
            NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue): UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16), // or your fieldFont
            NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue): UIColor.black, // or your fieldColor
            NSAttributedStringKey(rawValue: NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle.rawValue): NSParagraphStyle.default // or your style
        ]
    }
```

or:

```
class func getCustomStringStyle() -> [String: Any]
    {
        return [
            NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16),
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.black,
            NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle.rawValue:NSParagraphStyle.default
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.2
Built on example of user_Dennis

```
 func getCustomStringStyle() -> [NSAttributedString.Key: Any]
    {
        return [
            NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.font.rawValue): UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25), // or your fieldFont
            NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue): UIColor.black, // or your fieldColor
            NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle.rawValue): NSParagraphStyle.default // or your style
        ]
    }
```